# How do I run tslint against a single file?

Tags: angular, import, tslint, angular14, linter

I'm using Angular 14.  I have set up a rule in tslint to warn about unused imports, and I can fix this across my project by running

```
> tslint --config tslint-imports.json --fix --project .
```

However, what if I just want to run the fix on a single file?  I tried this

```
> tslint --config tslint-imports.json --fix ./src/app/services/my-products.service.ts
Warning: The 'no-unused-declaration' rule requires type information.
```

but besides the warning above, the file itself isn't fixed (it is fixed when it is run as part of the larger project initiative in the first code line above)

**Edit:** tslint-imports.json config file is

```
{
        "extends": [
                "tslint-etc"
        ],
        "rules": {
                "no-unused-declaration": true
        }
}
```

Comment: please provide the contents of your config file.

Comment: tslint-imports.json file is added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that [tslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint) was deprecated 3 years ago. Why did you use it together with Angular 14?

Switch to [eslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint) instead.
Please be aware that `eslint` does not have a feature like `no-unused-declaration` and it is [not planned to implement this](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2689).

But with some some extra plugins it is possible:

> eslint-plugin-import can do this with import/no-unused-modules:
>
> ```js
> {
>  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'import'],
>  rules: {
>    'import/no-unused-modules': [2, { unusedExports: true }],
>  },
> };
> ```

Source: [Github comment by golopot](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/371#issuecomment-494365731)